# Как получить данные из POST-запроса при возврате ответа 200 OK?

Tags: winapi, post, http

Использую функцию `HttpQueryInfo` пакета WinSDK из C++.

Вот что я получаю в ответ от сервера при запросе на скрипт. А хочется получить данные. Что нужно делать?

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OKServer: nginx/0.7.64Date: Fri, 14 Dec 2012 13:28:50 GMTContent-Type: text/html; charset=WINDOWS-1251Transfer-Encoding: chunkedConnection: keep-aliveX-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=h0ur9abofidnf2ms1nq6sjq7m7; path=/Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMTCache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0Pragma: no-cacheHTTP/1.1 200 OKServer: ngio
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так `HttpQueryInfo` даёт информацию о запросе, а не ответ на запрос. Другими словами, всё, что можно получить с помощью `HttpQueryInfo` - это только http-хэдер.

Видимо нужно использовать другую функцию.

Comment: @SoloMio, похоже [здесь](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa383766%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#HTTP_hierarchy) находится полезная инфа.

Думаю Вам надо дальше вызывать InternetReadFile.